# React: "Cmd-Click" a button that navigates somewhere. Best Practices?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have components that have buttons that work like this with `onClick`:

```
<Button
   onClick={() => {
     history.push(props.directLink);
   }}
...
...
...
```

Obviously, when you click, it routes to the internal page matching `props.directLink`. However, users sometime **cmd-click** buttons to open a new tab. I know how to browse to a new tab, that's not the issue -- The issue is how to detect users want to stay in the tab (simple mouse click) or open the link in a new tab (cmd-click).

How do I do this elegantly? Should I really be testing to see if Cmd is pressed during the click? Should I be using `<Link>` around the button instead of processing the click manually?

pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use `<a>` tags for links. This is the only way to get full experience which is not only click and cmd+click, but also shift+click (open in new window), context menu with all the link-specific options like different open modes, copy address etc. If you want to still use a button, you can wrap it with link

```
<a href="...">
  <button>I'm button!</button>
</a>
```